# Python 'dynamic' table

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a table with the code below:

```
if len(data_item_ready) > 1:  # se c'è almeno un item da testare
label = Label(text="Componenti da testare oggi:", font=('Kozuka Gothic Pro B' ,24))
label.grid()
root.check = []
colonne = ('component_type', 'serial_number', 'latest_note', 'test_after')
tabella = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=colonne, show='headings')
tabella.heading('component_type', text='Component Type')
tabella.column('component_type', width=140)
tabella.heading('serial_number', text='Serial Number')
tabella.column('serial_number', width=200)
tabella.heading('latest_note', text='Latest Note')
tabella.column('latest_note', width=750)
tabella.heading('test_after', text='Test after')
tabella.column('test_after', width=150)

righe = []
for n in range(1, len(data_item_ready)):
    righe.append((comp_item_ready[n], sn_item_ready[n], notes_item_ready[n], data_item_ready[n]))

for riga in righe:
    tabella.insert('', END, values=riga)
tabella.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Output:
[image: output:]

In this case I enter manually the width value for each column, is it possible to adjust this value based on the length of the text inside the column? For example, if the longest 'latest note' is 50 pixel, it will adapt automatically the size of the column to fit that text.

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what’s less clear is how this ought to be indented. Don’t make us guess; please [edit] to fix this. (On the desktop version of this site, paste your program, select it, and type ctrl-K to properly format it as code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tkinter.font.Font.measure()` function to get the width in pixels of a string.

- create an instance of `tkinter.font.Font`
- configure the treeview to use the font
- go through the strings in a column and get the width of the longest string using the `measure()`

```py
...
from tkinter.font import Font
...
# create an instance of Font
font = Font(family="Arial", size=12)
# set the treeview to use the font
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Treeview", font=font)
...
# a function to get the width in pixels of the longest string in a list
def max_width(item_list, font=font):
    width = 0
    for item in item_list:
        width = max(width, font.measure(item))
    return width
...
if len(data_item_ready) > 1:
    ...
    # max_width(...)+10 <- include left and right margins in a column
    tabella.column('latest_note', width=max_width(notes_item_ready)+10)
    ...
```